# Mongodb 4.41 does not start in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb

I installed Mongodb 4.4.1 following the documentation of the mongodb site. installation was smooth. But when I am checking the status of the mongod service, I am getting an error as below:

> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-09-16 22:22:23 IST; 6s ago
> Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
> Process: 36655 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, stat>    Main PID: 36655 (code=exited, status=14)
>
> Sep 16 22:22:22 Ubuntu-PC systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
> Sep 16 22:22:23 Ubuntu-PC systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process
> exited, code=exited, s> Sep 16 22:22:23 Ubuntu-PC systemd[1]:
> mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Even when I try to open mongo shell typing mongo, I get the following error:

> MongoDB shell version v4.4.1 connecting to:
> mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt
> failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused
> by :: Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
> @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1

The service is showing as started and enabled. Pleas help. Where have I done the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
service mongod stop

systemctl start mongod
```

To start using MongoDB:

```
mongo
```